# Error: Cannot find module "@org-name/package-name"

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules

So I have been stuck on this for few days now. I am trying to create a new npm package to wrap an API I've been working on.

Bundling the package seems to be working as far as I can see in the `/dist` folder. However, when I want to test it in a front-end project (test project using the lastest nextJS) it **fails during run time**.

I tried to use the package in two ways, I tried `npm link ./path_to_package` and by publishing the package to npm registry and then installing it normally like any other package.

The issue is that the class I'm importing is being resolved to the proper folder/file. And typescript is detecting the proper types, and its detecting the function names I'm trying to use.

However, **ONLY DURING RUN TIME** whenever I try to call that function from the package, I get the this following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@my-org/ncw-client'
>  7 | import { WallabyClient } from '@my-org/ncw-client';
```

Here is the entry point file (`src/index.ts`) exporting the class I am trying to call:

```
import { Wallet } from './resources';

export default class WallabyClient {
  public wallet: Wallet;

  constructor(config: { apiKey: string; baseUrl?: string }) {
    this.wallet = new Wallet(config);
  }
}
```

Could it be the `wallet` import in that file that's not being resolved?

My project looks like this:

```
ncw-client
├── dist
├── node_modules
├── src
│   ├── base.ts
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── resources
│       ├── index.ts // used to export everything from wallet and later from all of /resources
│       └── wallet
│           ├── index.ts
│           └── types.ts
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
```

My package.json for the SDK:

```
{
  "name": "@my-org/ncw-client",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.m.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/index.umd.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    "require": "./dist/index.js",
    "default": "./dist/index.modern.js"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "microbundle": "microbundle --tsconfig tsconfig.json --no-sourcemap",
    "build:esm": "tsc",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@types/estree": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "microbundle": "0.15.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public",
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "lib", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

Based on some readings and suggestions I've found in the last couple of days, I tried changing the module from `commonjs` to `ES5`, `ES6`, `ESNext` in tsconfig file, I tried changing the `type` in the package.json file to `module` I added few flags and removed them, but no combination of settings has worked so far.

Any pointers or readings that I can do would be greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue and didn't find an answer in the first place. But the solution:

You have to run `npm install` at the root folder of your monorepo, so the new package can be found at the root node_modules.

Details: https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/sharing-code/internal-packages

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For my small project, there is only one package.json at the root, and that's where I have been running `npm install`.